# Git hook for React Native / Expo app to prevent compile-time errors?

Tags: react-native, build, expo, githooks

There's a new open source project I'm working on that seems to frequently have syntax errors committed to the master branch. I'd like to configure a git hook that will notify contributors of basic errors before pushing their working branches to github.

**How can I set up a git hook to reject code with simple build errors for our React Native expo app?**

Currently it appears this project doesn't have any package.json scripts that perform test builds or anything similar that I can leverage, and unfortunately I don't know enough about expo to create one of my own. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're asking about is how to setup continuous integration. There are a lot of ways to do this. I'll talk a bit how I did it.

1. Install and setup web hook Relay (OR setup a server with a static URL)
2. Install Jenkins locally or on the server with static URL
3. [Setup web hook relay with Jenkins and Github](https://webhookrelay.com/blog/2017/11/23/github-jenkins-guide/)
4. Once the hook is in place and working you can add bash scripts in jenkins to git clone, build and test the expo project.
5. Send information back to github through the webhook (e.g. Build: failed/Success)

There are a number of guides online that can be useful.

**EDIT:**

Jenkins can automatically download github repository when someone pushes code or when a pull request is made.

Jenkins can run any bash script for building, testing, deploying

Jenkins can update github with a webhook with the results of the bash scripts

Jenkins can do so much more

[Useful link](https://applitools.com/blog/how-to-update-jenkins-build-status-in-github-pull-requests-step-by-step-tutorial/?utm_referrer=https://www.google.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your time & answer, but no, I'm really specifically interested in just using the git hooks for this purpose. They're lightweight and should be capable of this, as long as expo has a way to run a test build.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just catch new code that breaks a previous test you can use [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky). Sets up a git hook. You can also run a test with 'npm run test'.

Expo builds your project for you when you run expo build. It also builds in its own time (unless you have a priority expo account) and can take more than 3 hours to complete. You can link a builds success/failure to a git hook using husky, but you would be waiting 3+ hours before you can git push --causing a massive bottleneck in productivity.